# can you consider a series to be a sequence of sums?

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

for example

sequence: $1/(2^n), \qquad n\ge 0$

sequence for the series: $1, 1.5, 1.75, 1.875, \ldots$

and if so, does that mean you can use/extend sequence theorems for series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes in fact that is what a series is considered to be. When you ask about convergence of a series all you are really asking about is the convergence of its sequence of partial sums.

Comment: Have a look at this to go a little deeper: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)